# sklearn univariate feature selection

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to use sklearn univariate feature selection to filter out irrelevant features:

```
ufs = feature_selection.SelectPercentile(feature_selection.f_classif, percentile = 60)
X_default_cvtrain = ufs.fit_transform( X_cvtrain, Y_cvtrain )
```

However, I get this warning:

```
UserWarning: Duplicate scores. Result may depend on feature ordering.
             There are probably duplicate features, or you used a classification score for a regression task.
warn("Duplicate scores. Result may depend on feature ordering."
```

What does it mean? What is going on here?

Thanks.

Comment: What don't you understand in the warning message?

Comment: @ogrisel Sorry, I mean why this warning came up.

Comment: possible causes are: "There are probably duplicate features, or you used a classification score for a regression task." We cannot be more explicit than that: go and check your data.

Answer (score 5):

It means that there are duplicate scores, so the selected features depend on the feature ordering.
A probable cause is that you have duplicate features.

Comment: Being less pretentious after some coffee: It means that there are duplicate relevance (F) scores, so which features are selected depend on the ordering of features in the array.
A probable cause is that several features are identical.

Comment: Thx for ur help. But is it also possible that the value vectors of two different features happen to be the same?